# Strange behavior (bugs?) in Graphviz

Tags: graphviz

I'm trying to use the `dot` program included with GraphViz (version 2.28.0 (20121023.0419)) to convert the following graphviz file:

```
digraph {
1 [
  shape=none
  ,label=<<TABLE BGCOLOR="lightblue2" BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="0" STYLE="rounded" ><TR><TD><FONT FACE="Helvetica" POINT-SIZE="20">Heading 1</FONT></TD></TR>
                 <TR><TD>Body 1<BR /></TD></TR></TABLE>>
  ];
3 [
  shape=none
  ,label=<<TABLE><TR><TD><FONT FACE="Helvetica" POINT-SIZE="16">Heading 2</FONT></TD></TR>
                 <TR><TD>Body 2<BR /></TD></TR></TABLE>>
  ,color=lightblue2];
2 [
  shape=none
  ,label=<<TABLE><TR><TD><FONT FACE="Helvetica" POINT-SIZE="16">Heading 3</FONT></TD></TR>
                 <TR><TD>Line 1<BR />Line 2<BR /></TD></TR></TABLE>>
  ,color=lightblue2];
}
```

First, I tried running to create a PDF (same result on Linux and Mac OS):

> dot  -Tpdf  -Gcharset=utf8  test.dot > output.pdf

[image]

**Issues:**

1. Incorrect font rendering: Heading 1 is underlined, the Heading 3 is italic, but all of them are specified using the exact same font face.
2. Border around the first node: I specified `BORDER="0"` but apparently the border is visible anyway when using STYLE="rounded"...

Next I tried to create an SVG file instead, which solves the font rendering issues:

> dot  -Tsvg  -Gcharset=utf8  test.dot > output.svg

[image]

As you can see the text overflows the borders of the node. This happens even if I add a `FIXEDWIDTH="FALSE"` to the table.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just for the record, this rendered fine with dot-graphviz 2.36.0 under OS X 10.8.5.

Answer (score 0):

Good daytime!
I advise you to try downgrading to dot-graphviz of 2.26.3 version. I did the same as you and got the correct result apart from the fact that dot-program ignored attribute STYLE in first table. So it was not rounded.